# "Use of internet" or "internet usage"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, grammaticality

I am confused about the meaning of "use of internet" and "internet usage". Is there any difference between these two phrases? Does the phrase "use of internet" mean I utilize the internet or it means the benefit of using internet? And is it grammatically correct to use "usage of internet"?

Answer (score 2):

The two phrases are both grammatically correct and equally acceptable. They mean the exact same thing: Both refer to utilizing the Internet and are neutral as to its benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes *internet usage* will sound better than *use of internet*. *Use of internet* will give clarity in some contexts. Better listen to your lips. Use the phrase which sounds better.